# Python Selenium Webdriver doesn't give an error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Python code is as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import logging

driver_path = "/usr/bin/chromedriver1"

def setting_chrome_options():
     chrome_options = Options()
     chrome_options.add_addargument("--headless")
     # Here few other options are also configured

if __name__ =='__main__':
     try:
          driver = webdriver.chrome(executable_path=driver_path,options=setting_chrome_options())
     except ValueError:
          logging.error("Error at webdriver path or oprions")
```

In the above code, intentionally I typed the wrong `driver_path`. However, it doesn't raise an immediate exception and gets infinite stuck.

The aim is to get an exception when invalid path or options parameters are there.

I have tried to google, but couldn't find the explanation that why it goes into the wait state.

Comment: Intensively added `1` in the `driver_path = "/usr/bin/chromedriver1"`

Comment: At the risk of being insensitive, "don't do that".  That is a configuration parameter internal to the application, not something coming from user input.  If it is missing, it's an design flaw.  An exception is not the right way to handle it.  You could always use `os.path.exists`, I suppose.

Comment: Thanks Tim Roberts